# VIM code completion under ROS

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following this link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs to get my code completion working. On top of the plugin rosvim.vim installed, I also have OmniCppComplete. I don't get the code completion working under ROS, how should I do that? By the way, code completion for any other codes excluding ROS-related codes are just working out of the box.

Any ideas..

EDIT:

How should I tailor my ~/.vimrc file. Anyway. I've tried to add yours with the existing one like below:

```
syntax enable
se nu
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
filetype on
filetype plugin on
set nocp
autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
autocmd FileType javascript set omnifunc=javascriptcomplete#CompleteJS
autocmd FileType html set omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType css set omnifunc=csscomplete#CompleteCSS
autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags
autocmd FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
autocmd FileType c set omnifunc=ccomplete#CompleteCpp


set tags+=~/.vim/tags/ros
" OmniCppComplete settings to be tweaked
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch=1                                                                                         
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch=1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess=1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot=1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow=1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope=1
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces=["std","_GLIBCXX_STD"]
" Hotkey to generate tags for you current project
map <F5> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr>
```

*I've uninstalled and reinstalled the autocompletion with both methods below but still does not work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9559/vim-code-completion-under-ros/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-28**:
Thanks Eric for editing that..

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-28**:
Could you edit your post and set

tags around the .vimrc part. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To use OmniCppComplete with ROS, you have to generate a set of tags for the ROS stacks.  There are probably better ways of doing this, but I was successful with find and grep.

First, generate a list of files that you want to generate tags from:

```
find /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks | grep -E '*/include/*/.*\.(h|hpp)' > /tmp/ros.filelist
```

Then use ctags to generate a tags database from this list:

```
ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f /tmp/ros.tags -L /tmp/ros.filelist
```

Once you have done this, you can move your tags file into your ~/.vim directory

```
mv /tmp/ros.filelist ~/.vim/tags/ros
```

And edit your ~/.vimrc file accordingly

```
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/ros
" OmniCppComplete settings to be tweaked
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch=1                                                                                         
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch=1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess=1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot=1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow=1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope=1
let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces=["std","_GLIBCXX_STD"]
" Hotkey to generate tags for you current project
map <F5> :!/usr/bin/ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .<cr>
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-28**:
I've realized one thing. It works for the autocompletion provided  I have to press ctrl-N or ctrl-P while I'm in insert mode. All this while, it works well for stl just after "dot"(.) it straightaway suggests some options/members of the class say. Is it working that way using this ros tag? Another thing is that the options given are too broad in fact all words found in the source code, including the comments work and also author's name, somehow weird.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-27**:
yeah, I've updated the namespace, but, it's still does not work..huhu, I think there are still ways to resolve this problem..

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-27**:
Update your vimrc to let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces=["std","_GLIBCXX_STD","ros"]

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-26**:
it's a good suggestion I guess, how to add "ros" to my default namespace? I can try that at least to see the output..

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-26**:
You can load all of your tags, that shouldn't be a problem.  In fact, you probably want to keep the tags from qt, sdl, and boost in addition to the ros tags.  You may be able to add "ros" to your default namespaces, and that would cure your problem, I'm not sure.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-26**:
When I run command ":set tags", it returns   "tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS,~/.vim/tags/stl,~/.vim/tags/gl,~/.vim/tags/sdl,~/
.vim/tags/qt4,~/.vim/tags/ros", seems to be okay right? Let me explain about my directory components..In my .vim directory, it has "after",  "autoload",  "doc",  "omnicppcomplete.zip", "qttags_backup, "tags",  "tags_backup"..Going deeper, in ../tags/ros directory, there reside "ros.filelist" and "ros.filelist2" files..Should I put  "qttags_backup,  and "tags_backup" together with "ros.filelist" and "ros.filelist2" files..BTW,  "qttags_backup,  and "tags_backup" are my previous tags files that I have prior to setting up ros tags..

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-26**:
If you enter the command ":set tags" in VIM, you should see a list of tags files.  Make sure that you ~/.vim/tags/ros file is included in that list.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-26**:
"Are you sure that you are actually sourcing the tags file that you generated for ROS", what did you mean by sourcing the tags file? How can I check it? Thanks..

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-26**:
You can compare to my vim files, here: https://github.com/mjcarroll/dotfiles  Are you sure that you are actually sourcing the tags file that you generated for ROS?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-26**:
Some strange things happened. It partially works with the one on /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks directory. It can autocompletes for boost:: (trying on point_cloud_converter package) but for ros:: still fails (expecting NodeHandle). The one my home directory is still not working (pattern not found returned)..Any remedy for this?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-26**:
Following the guide that I posted above, point cloud and ros:: sucessfully completes.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-25**:
I think it's also useful if you can check the command that I've invoked. Below is the command that I've run: (1) find /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks | grep -E '*/include/*/.*.(h|hpp)' > /tmp/ros.filelist (2) ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f /tmp/ros.tags -L /tmp/ros.filelist (3) mv /tmp/ros.filelist ~/.vim/tags/ros (4) find /home/user/dev/code | grep -E '*/include/*/.*.(h|hpp)' > /tmp/ros.filelist2 (5)  ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f /tmp/ros.tags -L /tmp/ros.filelist2  (6) mv /tmp/ros.filelist2 ~/.vim/tags/ros

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-25**:
Did you mean at the end I will have two files (one for /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks and another one for /home/user/code/dev ) of ros.filelist in ~/.vim/tags/ros directory? Is my edited version of ~/.vimrc file correct (please refer to the question part, the bottom part in the "EDIT" section)?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-25**:
Obviously, you would have to repeat the process for each of the directories that you keep your ROS files in.  In my case, I also keep (personal) ROS stacks in ~/devel/ros, so I have an additional step to make sure that the */include/*.h files from that directory as well.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-25**:
Since my ROS files also reside in /home/user/code/dev then I do like this instead. "find /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks | grep -E '*/include/*/.*.(h|hpp)' > /tmp/ros.filelist && find /home/user/code/dev  | grep -E '*/include/*/.*.(h|hpp)' > /tmp/ros.filelist"..is that right that way?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-25**:
Thanks mjcarroll, kindly refer to .vimrc file that I've included in the question part.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-25**:
Yeah, Omni completion is not very straightforward to set up.  I can't speak to that particular error, but if you have a vanilla Ubuntu and ROS install, my scripts above will work.  I would check over your ~/.vimrc file again and make sure you aren't doing anything "bad" elsewhere in the file.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-24**:
I still got this error message: "-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found" What is possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following .vimrc snippet is mostly from [here](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2367-the-autocompletion-c-c-in-vim). Visit the link to see how to create stl, qt, sdl and qt4 tags (or deactivate the "set"-lines).

The only ros-specific part is `rospack cflags-only-I` in the third line, which lists all the include directories of the ros package in which you are editing files for the ctags command (this assumes the current working dir of vim is your projects directory, see below, which btw also allows you to use :mak). With this, hitting F11 will generate completion tags for your current file's project.

In contrast to the solution of mjcarroll this creates a tagfile in your project's directory, which is specific to the dependencies of your project. Therefore you need to create the tags (F11) for each of the packages in which you are editing files. On the other hand vim should be faster looking up its tag database.

```
map  :!ctags -R --languages=c++ --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
"This is to tag the include for ros packages the current project depends on
map  :!ctags -R --languages=c++ --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q . `rospack cflags-only-I`
"map  :!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q ~/local/usr/include/
" configure tags - add additional tags here or comment out not-used ones
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/stdlibtags
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/gltags
"set tags+=~/.vim/tags/sdl
set tags+=~/.vim/tags/qt4tags
" OmniCppComplete
let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1
let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1
"let OmniCpp_DefaultNamespaces = ["std", "_GLIBCXX_STD"]

" automatically open and close the popup menu / preview window
au CursorMovedI,InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|silent! pclose|endif
set completeopt=menuone,menu,preview ",longest 
"END Omnicompletion
```

Vim's present working dir (:pwd) needs to be the root directory of your package (i.e., the output of `rospack find <yourpackage>`) because calling "rospack cflags-only-I" without package name argument will use the current dir as package name. This is the case if you start vim in that directory or use :cd to change there. Alternatively you could somehow (I do not know how, though) find out the package name of the project your file belongs to, to give it to the rospack call.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-04-06**:
Do you think 64-bit machine is an issue here?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-04-01**:
It would be great if you can add my skype id "alfarobi1" so we can further discuss about that..Thanks Felix..

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-04-01**:
Yeah I think we won't solve this with these comments. If you are comfortable with it, an alternative would be that you create an unpriviledged user on your system, so I can log in via ssh and try to set up that user's vim settings.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-04-01**:
I got your point. I've even tried to uninstall and reinstall all the stuff and dependencies, it still does not work..perhaps I've to go to meet you from Bonn to Freiburg :-)

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-31**:
Usually in Linux configuration files in your home directory (~/.vimrc) are loaded after ones outside, so they are used both, but the settings in the file in your home directory overwrite the other ones, if you have duplicate settings.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-31**:
It could be the one in /usr/share/vim (vimrc file instead of .vimrc), but my confusion is why you and mjcarroll mentioned about ~/.vimrc(which is in home directory)? Can you check yours, and do you have it in both places as well?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-31**:
Are you sure about the command because after running it, it's just an empty file.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-31**:
in vim open $MYVIMRC, i.e. do ":e $MYVIMRC". That is the right one

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-31**:
I think we are about to find the solution..when I locate vimrc, it gives another place where vimrc file is located. One is in home directory but named as .vimrc (all this while I've been tweaking this one) and another is located  in directory /usr/share/vim but named as vimrc(without dot in front)..So, which one actually, I'm supposed to deal with?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-31**:
Regarding the general one (non-ros), it works well since before I posted this question and until now it is still working..Just I need to make the ROS-related one also to be working.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-31**:
I don't know what's wrong, this works for me. Have you tried to setup the general (i.e. non-ros) omnicompletion as in the link I posted? Does that work? Or is omnicompletion broken in general?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-30**:
I would say it still does not work because as I type say, ros::, it returns "-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
". It is supposed to give some autocompetion (member) there. I only can have the autocompletion if I press "i" or "a" first, then it gives some autocompetions. Even so, the given autocompletion is rather strange which contains all words in my source code including my name :-( Or may be the way I invoke it is wrong? any key binding that I do not know..can you remind or show me if any missing?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-30**:
That's fine, it can't find one of the files (maybe some rospack caching error). Completion should work now, as ctags still generates the tags for anything else.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-30**:
After deleting the old "tags", it returns this error "ctags: Warning: cannot open source file "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/msg_gen/cpp/include" : No such file or directory

Press ENTER or type command to continue", when i navigate to the directory, there is no such "msg_gen" directory under "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib" in fact, Any way to resolve it?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-30**:
Sounds like there already is a file called "tags". See what it is, and delete if appropriate

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-30**:
The error msg is "ctags: "tags" doesn't look like a tag file; I refuse to overwrite it.

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
"

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-29**:
Ah, no I misunderstood the error msg. The problem is "/bin/bash: rospack: command not found" if you use sudo. What happens if you press f5 when you started vim  as unprivileged user in a package directory that you have write access to?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-29**:
"In your original .vimrc you have /usr/bin/ctags, try that instead of ctags only", how to try this? I have ctags installed, and I've tried the package in my home directory.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-29**:
Could be several things. Do you have ctags installed? In your original .vimrc you have /usr/bin/ctags, try that instead of ctags only. Also, please try it without sudo (i.e., not as root) in a package you created within your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in a place you have write access.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-29**:
i've got one error "Press ENTER or type command to continue
ctags: Warning: cannot open source file "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/msg_gen/cpp/include" : No such file or directory", when i navigate to the directory, there is no such "msg_gen" directory under "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib" in fact..How to remedy this?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-29**:
I think "sudo su" is useless, instead i just run "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf$ sudo vim src/tf.cpp". After pressing f5 I got an error message "/bin/bash: rospack: command not found
ctags: "tags" doesn't look like a tag file; I refuse to overwrite it.
shell returned 1"

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-29**:
I've run "sudo su" already..I've also tried tf::but still does not work. For f11 you mentioned is it to be run every time we want to edit our file? I've change from f11 to f5 because f11 is for minimize/maximize terminal window on my machine..

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-29**:
Could the problem be, that you do not have write access to "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf"? Vim will try to store a file "tags" in the present working directory. Also, for completion of std:: (which is non-ros) follow the steps described in the above link.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-29**:
I've tried to try for tf, editing tf.cpp..so, I navigate to the root package & run the command like this as "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf$ vim src/tf.cpp ". In editing mode I've tried to edit std::, but i doesn't work..What command was probably missing? I probably need to press F5 or something like that..

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-29**:
With "root directory of your package" I mean the dir you get if you type "ropack find X", where X is the name of the pkg in which you are editing files. I.e., for a current standard ros installation the root pkg dir of "tf" is "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/geometry/tf".

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-29**:
Sorry for my slow getting it..Do you mean I've to navigate to ~/.vim directory, then from there I start my vim say: "vim ~/code/dev/try_node.cpp"? Am I right?

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-28**:
Edited the post to answer to your 1. question. :mak calls "make" from vim in the current dir. The output can be examined in the quickfix window (:copen). To jump to errors, double click or enter on err msg in the compiler output. Make the dir quest. a new post, hard to answer in comment w/ 300 chars

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-03-28**:
What do you mean by "this assumes the current working dir of vim is your projects directory, which btw also allows you to use :mak"? Is it also possible for my ros directory to be maintained in /home/user/code/dev instead of /home/user? This is because I do not want to keep my ros-related stuff the same directory as ~/.vim. Another thing is what is the use of :mak?